# How to change html output through javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I sincerely apologise if this question has been asked already but I'm fairly new to this and couldn't find the answer online...

I am learning about using javascript with html and I am trying to change the html output depending on what the user inputs. Somthing like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<script>
function showCost() {
    var registrationJS = document.forms["myForm"]["registration"].value;
    var adsJS = document.forms["myForm"]["ads"].value;
    var cost = 0;
    if (registrationJS == "premium") {
        cost += 50;
    }
    if (ads == "yes") {
        cost += 2;
    }
    cost = '$'+cost;
    document.write(cost);
}
</script>

<head>
</head>

<body>
<form name="myForm" method="post">
Registration:<select id="registration">
    <option value="premium">Premium</option>
    <option value="free">Free</option>
</select>

Pay to get rid of ads?<br>
<input type="radio" id="ads" value="yes">Yes<br>
<input type="radio" id="ads" value="no">No<br>

Cost: <-- display cost -->
<script>showCost(); <-- ???? --> </script>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Basically, how can I make display the cost, and how can I make it so it updates every time I change one of the outputs it will display the new cost?

Btw I am aware that if I make it premium and then free it wont go back down I'm just trying to get the basics of the html part and the syntax... Thank you! :)

Comment: Posted an answer for you, and what ever you do, don't start using inline script, like `onblur=...` or `onchange=...`, it is so much more powerful and easier to maintain how I showed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make a div:

```
Cost: <div id = "cost"></div>
```

and in the function instead of document.write(cost), do

```
document.getElementById('cost').innerHTML = cost;
```

to update with user input use suitable event handler: [Events](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_eventattributes.asp)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer... so would something like <select id="registration" onblur="return showCost()"></select> work?

Comment: No. you have to get value of select on change and then make a logic. [Onchange Link](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way you can do, using event listener.

```js
(function(sel,inp) {

  function showCost() {

    var cost = 0;

    if (sel.value == "premium") {
      cost += 50;
    }
    if (inp[0].checked) {
      cost += 2;
    }
    cost = '$'+cost;
    document.getElementById('cost').textContent = cost;
  }
  
  showCost();

  sel.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
    showCost(e);
  })

  for (var i = 0; i < inp.length; i++) {
    inp[i].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
      showCost(e);
    })
  }

})(document.querySelector('.registration'),document.querySelectorAll('input'));
```

```html
<form name="myForm" method="post">
Registration:<select class="registration">
    <option value="premium">Premium</option>
    <option selected value="free">Free</option>
</select>
<br>
Pay to get rid of ads?<br>
<input type="radio" name="ads" value="yes">Yes<br>
<input type="radio" name="ads" checked value="no">No<br>

Cost:<span id="cost"></span> 

</form>
```